# elasticsearch comparison between fields

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have documents with the following fields:
`{field1, field2, ... fieldn}`

I need to run some queries where some of the conditions will require a comparison between two or more fields. like `fieldX = fieldY`

In standard SQL, an example could be:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE farePrice>100 AND originRegion = destinationRegion
```

I'be been reading some documentation, and it looks "scripting" could be the only way to achieve this? Or are there any other options?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the script filter -

```
{
  "filtered": {
    "query": {
      "range": {
        "farePrice": {
          "gt": 100
        }
      }
    },
    "filter": {
      "script": {
        "script": "doc['originRegion'].value ==  doc['destinationRegion'].value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can find more information at [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-filter.html#query-dsl-script-filter) and [here](http://blog.qbox.io/elasticsearch-scripting-filtering) .

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. I supposed scripting is then the only way to compare fields between them. Has scripting a negative impact in the performance?

Comment: Scripting is generally CPU intensive.

Comment: For ES 5.0+ you'll need to use query instead of filtered at the top leave, e.g.: `"query":{"bool":{"must": {"range":...}},"filter":...}`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40519806/no-query-registered-for-filtered

Comment: How would you do this with lucene syntax?

Comment: @Sam - This operation is done on doc values and not reverse index. So queries in Lucene wont help. You will need to write a extension to custom collector interface or something and solve it