# Elasticsearch compare two fields

Tags: elasticsearch

For example MySQL query

```
SELECT fields_a, fields_b FROM table WHERE fields_a > fields_b;
```

I am trying to implement for elasticsearch. I've tried, as follows:

```
$where = [ "query" => [ "filter" => [ "script" => [ "script" => "doc[\"fields_a\"].value > doc[\"fields_b\"].value" ] ] ] ];
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, I've tried, as follows:  `$where = [
            "query" => [
                "filter" => [
                    "script" => [
                        "script" => "doc[\"fields_a\"].value  > doc[\"fields_b\"].value"
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];`

Comment: What is your error ? Problem ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [elasticsearch comparison between fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708612/elasticsearch-comparison-between-fields)

Answer (score 8):

this should work for me

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "script": {
                    "script": "doc['field_a'].value > doc['field_b'].value"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

To select only few fields instead of the whole source document use [stored_fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-stored-fields.html) `"stored_fields": ["field_a","field_b"]`  and make sure to have those fields as `store=true` in mappings .

```
{
stored_fields": ["field_a","field_b"]
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "script": {
                    "script": "doc['field_a'].value > doc['field_b']"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```