# Filtering by 2 field values in elastic?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica

I am not sure how to best word this question, so I will just use MySQL example.

So in MySQL, I can write query like so:

`SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_field >= some_other_field`

What query would be equivalent of this in Elastic Search?

Bonus question: is it implemented in Elastica PHP client?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064956/elasticsearch-compare-two-fields

Answer (score 0):

Try to search with this query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "script": {
          "script": "doc['some_field'].value >= doc['some_other_field'].value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Based on: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/query-dsl-script-query.html

Be warned that in [previous version](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/query-dsl-script-query.html) we had a little bit different syntax.