# Condition based query in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to build query based on the condition in elastic search ?

E.g

```
{
 "match": {
      "ticket_group.marketplaceticket_source_id": (q.preferredProvider!=0) ? q.preferredProvider:""                                        
 }    
}
```

In above coe if "`q.preferredProvider`" is 0 then I want to omit condition for "`ticket_group.marketplaceticket_source_id`" or you can say that "`ticket_group.marketplaceticket_source_id`" can take any value otherwise "`ticket_group.marketplaceticket_source_id`" should match with "`q.preferredProvider`"

How can I write it in elastic search ?

Comment: You may want to clarify what you are trying to do here exactly. Also, what is q?

Meanwhile, you may be able to use a script query for this. Another option is to use function score queries where you use filters on the functions. Also, a simple bool query might be good enough here.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will will help u :-

Check these link also [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708612/elasticsearch-comparison-between-fields) [link2](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html) [link3](https://qbox.io/blog/elasticsearch-scripting-filtering)

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                "match": {
                    "q.preferredProvider": 0
                }
            },
            "must": {
                "match": {
                    "script": {
                        "script": {
                            "doc['ticket_group.marketplaceticket_source_id'].value ==  doc['q.preferredProvider'].value"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```