# Query string query - two fields must match

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I'm using ElasticSearch 5.1 and I wonder if it's possible to build query string query which will match all records where fields `field_1` and `field_2` are the same.

At the time of executing query I don't know what value they store. All I know is mapping which is `keyword`.

So for example data:

```
{"id": 1, "field_1": "foo", "field_2": "foo"}
{"id": 2, "field_1": "foo", "field_2": "bar"}
```

when I execute such query I want to get only record with id 1 because `field_1`===`field_2`

Thanks!

Comment: Would it be conceivable to index another boolean field that contains the information (i.e. true if the fields match and false otherwise)? Or do you have too many field combinations to check?

Comment: There are only 2 fields I need to check but this would have to be updated frequently. Looks like a solution. Thanks.

Comment: When you update one or the other field, you can also update the boolean flag. Without that, you'll have to resort to using a script query which is much less performant and optimal.

Comment: Please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708612/elasticsearch-comparison-between-fields)

Answer (score 2):

If you can use another query than `query string`, what about a `script query`?

From https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-script-query.html

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "script" : {
                    "script" : {
                        "inline": "doc['field_1'].value == doc['field_2'].value"
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```