# Temporary table alternative in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a scenerio where i'm filtering some records from a table and reusing the same intermediate tables to join on a column. My query looks something like this

```
select * from
(select poscode  from test where  AccountNo='270679' )AS FD 
JOIN 
(select poscode from test where AccountNo!='270679')AS MD
ON FD.poscode=MD.poscodE
```

I can put two get request on my data but and get the result but how will i use the concept of temporaray tables here in elastic search as i created two FD,MD in sql and put a join between them.
I was able to get some info from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708612/elasticsearch-comparison-between-fields) but not sure how to put all that together

Comment: @Vineeth Mohan  if you can help in this?

Comment: If I understand your SQL correctly, Wouldn't this be just a terms aggregation on poscode followed by a filter on AccountNo?

Comment: Yes but how we will do this operations in one go in elastic search. I was thinking about using python scripting, though it's cpu expensive @sramalingam24

Comment: I would need to see your mapping and example docs before i can even attempt it